# Exchange 2013 mailbox forwarding even though it's disabled

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2013

I had a user which had his email forwarded to gmail.com. Latly i disabled that option via ECP and it has no such settings as forwarding. But then his emails never get into his mailbox.

```
HARED... SMTP     test@poland.pl                   {account@reprezenta... T34
RECEIVE  SMTP     test@poland.pl                   {account@reprezenta... T34
RESOLVE  ROUTING  test@poland.pl                   {Account@rs.pl}             T34
REDIRECT AGENT    test@poland.pl                   {Account@rs.pl}             T34
EXPAND   AGENT    test@poland.pl                   {account.r@gmail.com}           T34
AGENT... AGENT    test@poland.pl                   {Account@rs.pl, account... T34
RESUBMIT AGENT    test@poland.pl                   {Account@rs.pl, account... T34
DROP     ROUTING  test@poland.pl                   {account.r@gmail.com}           T34
AGENT... AGENT    test@poland.pl                   {account.r@gmail.com}           T34
```

And this is with forwarding disabled. Yet if i go again to ECP and I see this message:

[image]

If the fields are empty when I am setting them up why show this message?

I can confirm now with:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-Mailbox | Where {$_.ForwardingAddress -ne $null}

Name                      Alias                ServerName       ProhibitSendQuota
----                      -----                ----------       -----------------
Account           account           exchange      Unlimited
```

But I've even run following command:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-Mailbox | Where {$_.ForwardingAddress -ne $null} | Set-Mailbox -ForwardingAddress $null -De
liverToMailboxAndForward $false
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-Mailbox | Where {$_.ForwardingAddress -ne $null}
```

No results. I go into GUI the forwarding address is cleaned.

[image]

I set it again just for test and again message about forwarding email being there.

[image]

So what's wrong? It's Exchange 2013 ->  Version 15.0 (Build 775.38). So CU3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i went further with this investigation. The thing here to check was: `forwardingsmtpaddress` which wasn't empty.

```
get-mailbox -Identity account | fl alias, forwardingaddress, forwardingsmtpaddress
```

Which seems to stay set even thou it was disabled via GUI. After I cleaned it up it started working correctly. Why would GUI unchecking and even powershell commands not work as they should when `forwardingsmtpaddress` is a bit over my head. It seems to be a bug in Exchange 2013 CU3 as far as I can tell.

```
Get-Mailbox | Where {$_.ForwardingAddress -ne $null} | Set-Mailbox -ForwardingAddress $null -ForwardingSmtpAddress $null -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $false
```

This cleaned it up (although it only works when forwarding was enabled). I would be happy to know why this is why it is. I did some checking and it seems the field `forwardingsmtpaddress` doesn't get set when setting up contact forwarding so why was it set this time. Oh well. Hopefully someone will find it useful.